# Flutter Firestore NoSuchMethodError

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm developing app with flutter and trying to get data from firestore by using streambuilder method like so.

```
body: new StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(uid).collection('userInfo').document(uid).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return new Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  radius: 48.0,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
                ),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
                new Text(snapshot.data['name'], 
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0)),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35.0)),
              ],
            ),
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Icon(
                          Icons.accessibility,
                          size: 18.0,
                        ),
                        new Text('Age',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.blue)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0)),
                    new Text(snapshot.data['age'].toString(), style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
                  ],
                ),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0)),
                new Divider(color: Colors.grey, height: 1.0),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0)),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Icon(
                          Icons.place,
                          size: 18.0,
                        ),
                        new Text('State',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 11.0, color: Colors.blue)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0)),
                    new Text(snapshot.data['state'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
                  ],
                ),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0)),
                new Divider(color: Colors.grey, height: 1.0),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0)),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Icon(
                          Icons.audiotrack,
                          size: 18.0,
                        ),
                        new Text('Hobby',
                            style: new TextStyle( fontSize: 11.0, color: Colors.blue)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0)),
                    new Text(snapshot.data['hobby'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0)),
                  ],
                ),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0)),
                new Divider(color: Colors.grey, height: 1.0),
              ],
            ),
            new SizedBox(height: 45.0),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('New Request',
                  style:
                      new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0)),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              onPressed: () {
                _toNewRequest();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
        return new Center(
          child: new Text('You havent set profile'),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

but error says this

> flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>       StreamBuilder(dirty, state: flutter:
>        _StreamBuilderBaseState>#f91a2) The method '[]' was
>   called on null.  Receiver: null Tried calling:[]
>   ("name")

but if I refresh(restart maybe) the app, click the green arrow,

[image]

then it shows data correctly.
why is this not working when app launches?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: instead of checking for (snapshot.hasData), check for (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)

Comment: Thank you for the comment but still not working.

Comment: By still not working, did you mean the error still appears or the data doesn't load? the check is only to prevent you from accessing snapshot.data when the stream is not active. To actually check if you have data coming in, print out the snapshot.data.data

Comment: error still says `The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null  Tried calling: []("name")` I found out that `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>` doesn't support this method `snapshot.data['name']`

Comment: I guess, it's supposed to be snapshot.data.data. It's always a good idea to see by printing out snapshot.data or snapshot.data.data before trying to access it. In your case it is mentioned clearly that you're trying to access data on a null object.

Comment: I think problem is `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>`. with this snapshot `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>` I can get value `snapshot.data['key']` do you know how to use `streamBuilder` with `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>`?

Comment: Yes, I have a working solution. I'll post it as an answer since I've seen lotta people asking the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering with example code because of multiple questions on the same.
This can be used as a reference to using streamBuilder with Firestore.

Stream Builder Example :

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: getClientProfile().snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshots) {
          if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            Client client = Client.from(snapshots.data);
            return Column(
              children: [
                HeaderDetails(client.productCategories, client.businessName,
                    client.coverPhoto, client.avatarPhoto),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                _displayInformationCard(
                    client.businessCategory, client.businessDescription),
                _locationInformationCard(client.address.getFullAddress()),
                _contactInformation(client),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.warning),
                  ),
                  Text('Error in loadind data')
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

firestore call example :

```
    DocumentReference getClientProfile() {
        return _fireStore.collection(SELLERS_COLLECTION).document(docId);
    }
```

and the model class, to structure your document in dart :

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Client {
  final DocumentReference documentReference;
  String sellerId;
  String businessName, businessDescription, businessCategory;
  List productCategories;
  String coverPhoto, avatarPhoto;
  Representative representative;
  Address address;

  Client.data(this.documentReference,
      [this.sellerId,
      this.businessName,
      this.businessDescription,
      this.businessCategory,
      this.productCategories,
      this.coverPhoto,
      this.avatarPhoto,
      this.representative,
      this.address]) {
    this.sellerId ??= '';
    this.businessName ??= '';
    this.businessDescription ??= '';
    this.businessCategory ??= '';
    this.productCategories ??= [];
    this.coverPhoto ??= '';
    this.avatarPhoto ??=
        '';
  }

  factory Client.from(DocumentSnapshot document) => Client.data(
        document != null ? document.reference : null,
        document.data['sellerId'],
        document.data['businessName'],
        document.data['businessDescription'],
        document.data['businessCategory'],
        document.data['productCategories'],
        document.data['coverPhoto'],
        document.data['avatarPhoto'],
        Representative.from(document.data['representative']),
        Address.from(document.data['pickupAddress']),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'sellerId': sellerId,
      'businessName': businessName,
      'businessDescription': businessDescription,
      'businessCategory': businessCategory,
      'productCategories': productCategories,
      'coverPhoto': coverPhoto,
      'avatarPhoto': avatarPhoto,
      'representative': representative.toMap(),
      'pickupAddress': address.toMap(),
    };
  }


}

class Address {
  String building;
  String street;
  String location;
  double lat;
  double lng;

  Address.data(this.building, this.street, this.location, this.lat, this.lng) {
    this.building ??= '';
    this.street ??= '';
    this.location ??= '';
    this.lat ??= 0.0;
    this.lng ??= 0.0;
  }

  factory Address.from(address) => Address.data(address['building'],
      address['street'], address['location'], address['lat'], address['lng']);

  getFullAddress() {
    return building + ', ' + street + '\n' + location;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'building': building,
      'street': street,
      'location': location,
      'lat': lat,
      'lng': lng,
    };
  }
}

class Representative {
  String representativeName;
  String contactNumber;
  String email;

  Representative.data(this.representativeName, this.contactNumber, this.email) {
    this.representativeName ??= '';
    this.contactNumber ??= '';
    this.email ??= '';
  }

  factory Representative.from(representative) => Representative.data(
      representative['representativeName'],
      representative['contactNumber'],
      representative['email']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'representativeName': representativeName,
      'contactNumber': contactNumber,
      'email': email,
    };
  }
}
```

The code was built using [this](https://youtu.be/w2TcYP8qiRI) as the reference.

Comment: how to pass the data you get here thought the widgets?